# Perform an inner join soql on arbitrary values

Tags: soql

I have some custom fields on `Account` and a custom object with some custom fields.

i want to find id from my custom object and id of accounts that have the same field value

I tried something like:

```
select Id, (SELECT Id FROM Account 
WHERE My_Field__c = My_Custom_Object__c.My_Field__c) FROM My_Custom_Object__c
```

I also tried

```
select Id, (SELECT Id FROM Account 
WHERE Account.My_Field__c = My_Custom_Object__c.My_Field__c) FROM My_Custom_Object__c
```

I get `Unknown error parsing query`

I need to get this in a single SOQL query so i can get it via iOS Mobile SDK through the API, without writing my own Apex (and avoiding the two queries, because also i'd have to group results and i may easily exceed the 50K governor limit).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to join on arbitrary fields. The only fields which support joins in SOQL are relationship fields (`Lookup` and `Master-Detail`).

Comment: Do you happen to maybe have some official documentation that states that this is not possible? Need it for management conversations...

Comment: There used to be an awesome guide to SOQL joins I would link people to, but it got moved a few months back and I haven't been able to track down its new location.

Comment: @AdrianLarson https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006tju ...?